# Simplifying javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple fadeouts happening at the same time on various Ids, Is there any way of setting this up in one line as example:

This:

```
$("#bottle").on('click', function() {
  $("#container_inner01").fadeIn(1100);
  $("#container_inner02").fadeOut(1100);
  $("#container_inner03").fadeOut(1100);
  $("#container_inner04").fadeOut(1100);
  $("#container02").fadeOut(1100);
})
```

turned it to this:

```
$("#bottle").on('click', function() {
  $("#container_inner01").fadeIn(1100);
  $("#container_inner02,#container_inner02,#container_inner03,#container_inner04,#container02").fadeOut(1100);
})
```

I am sure its possible and its some syntax error I am doing.

Comment: What you have should work.

Comment: What's your problem? Do you get an error? Do only a number of animations work? Does nothing happen at all?

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the very end, in both examples. Any errors showing up in the JS console?

Comment: As a side note, you've got #container_inner02 in there twice on your new line

Comment: @PaulRoub - no he's not.

Comment: Working fine here, by the way: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/GgoVJW

Comment: @j08691 It's since been edited.

Comment: Why is#container_inner02 listed twice?

Comment: Yea I spotted the container_inner duplicate after posting, I am not getting errors, just wanted to know a way of making the code smaller and neater as I have to do this on 4 stages and the code is getting long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not give your elements a `class` and execute the script that way?

```
$("#bottle").on('click', function () {
    $("#container_inner01").fadeIn(1100);
    $('.test').fadeOut(1100);
});
```

[**JsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ucs1vv3n/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(function($){
    $("#bottle").on('click', function() {
        $('#container_inner01').fadeIn(1100);
        $('#container_inner02,#container_inner03,#container_inner04,#container02').fadeOut(1100);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing what you have in the second script:

```
$("#bottle").on('click', function() {
  $("#container_inner01").fadeIn(1100);
  $("#container_inner02,#container_inner02,#container_inner03,#container_inner04,#container02").fadeOut(1100);
});
```

Will work, although you can sum this up to this:

```
$("#bottle").on('click', function() {      
    $("#container_inner01").fadeIn(1100);
    $("#container_inner02,#container_inner03,#container_inner04,#container02").fadeOut(1100);
});
```

Note that you have `#container_inner02,#container_inner02` in you script repeating. Another way to do this is to add a class to all of them and using that class affects each item:

```
$("#bottle").on('click', function() {      
    $("#container_inner01").fadeIn(1100);
    $(".myClassName").fadeOut(1100);
});
```

Comment: Including `#container_inner01` in the `fadeOut()` instead of fading it *in* isn't exactly the same as the original two steps.

Comment: Your second code ommits the fact that the OP is using fadeIn for #container_inner01 and fadeOut for the remaining containers

Comment: @PaulRoub Oh your right, didn't notice it was different. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @AGE Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't notice the `fadeIn()` and thought they were all `fadeOut()`.